# How can I add text to the bottom of the row using html?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have an image and a text on my page. Image of my page image appears on the left, text on the right side looks nice. I want to add a text under the text. How can I do that? How to add another text to the bottom of the text. I've added the  element directly to the code I have written, but this time it's not just underneath it. I want a single image and two text. How do I add a new text under the text I wrote?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl = "/Images/a.png"</td>
<td style= padding-left: 20px;> ID="ContentLabel"</td> 
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This does not make sense. Please edit for clarity.

Comment: you want one text in one line and another text in second line as below to that first text. Is that your query?

Comment: Can you provide an image or drawing of what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl = "/Images/a.png".  
</td>
<td style= padding-left: 20px;>
<div>
 <p>text1</p>
 <p>text2</p>
</div>
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```